# Can't open jupyter notebook from terminal (Python 3.6)

Tags: python, python-3.x, terminal, jupyter-notebook, macos-sierra

I really need your help, did extensive searching online but couldn't figure out, why I can't open the jupyter notebook from my terminal. If I type in

```
jupyter notebook
```

in the terminal, it says "Error executing Jupyter command 'notebook': [Errno 2] No such file or directory". So I checked if it's even installed with the command

```
jupyter --version
```

and the result was "4.3.0". Then I tried to change the directory to the path to the config-dir aswell as the data-dir, neither one did work. So I tried to uninstall with

```
pip uninstall jupyter
```

and I got the output "Cannot uninstall requirement jupyter, not installed". I tried to re-install it aswell with

```
pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall --no-cache-dir jupyter
```

but didn't work too.

Can anyone help? How can I delete everything related to python from my mac so I can install it from zero again?

Thanks for help! --batman

Comment: Are you running an environment like `pyenv` or `virtualenv` or a `conda` one?

Comment: @Gilbert Thank you for you answer, well, I did install e few weeks ago Anaconda, but didn't like it, so I uninstalled it again. Now I need the jupyter notebook anyway so I installed it with `pip install jupyter notebook` from the terminal. I wasn't sure if I need an environment, because I can run it on my windows10 from the cmd with no issues though.

Comment: What OS are you running?

Comment: @Gilbert MacOS Sierra (10.12.6)